# Placing a Button on the clipped border in html

Tags: html

I want to place a button on a border of a div that is clipped through the clip-path property. i have been able to clip the border but can't seem to place the button on the curved border. i have tried everything but can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance. I have posted the code below. Please check it out! Thanks.

```css
.learningSection {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #6a0bf5 -0.87%, #2461ed 100%);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding: 65px;
}
.freeTrialBtn {
    width: 217px;
    height: 35px;
    background: #11ee92;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
    border-radius: 25px;
    align-items: center;
    border: 0;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 490px)
.learningSection {
    content: "";
    position: relative;
    clip-path: ellipse(400px 100% at top);
}
```

```html
<div class="learningSection">
    <div class="learningSectionTextandBtn">
      <h1 class="learningHeading">Start Learning</h1>
      <p class="learningText">
        Learn 12 different languages in just ten minutes a day.
      </p>
      <form action="/enternumber" id="enternumber" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="pckg" id="daily" value="jazz-sku-1-day" />
        <button class="freeTrialBtn" style="margin-top: 20px;">
          <p style="text-align:center;margin: 0;">Start Free Trial!</p>
        </button>
      </form></div>
```

[I want the result the image to be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLYdc.png)

[but the result is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9Rlx.png)

Comment: Your clip-path is not shown , at least for me. But iam sure you can make it happen with position absolute

Comment: Stack overflow is not correctly executing the code. Plus the clipping will only be achieved when the media query is runned. Where should i use the position absolute because i have tried it and it hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you know what you are doing with Clip-path but remember that clip-path , CLIPS all its container so every element will get removed so you can't use elements on its border because they will get clipped so you need to use another container to use elements on it. Here is the code with clip-path.

```css
body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .container {
            background-color: green;
            width: auto;
            position: relative;
            height: 450px;
        }
        .parent {
            width: 100%;
            height: 420px;
            overflow: hidden;
            position:relative;
            margin:0 auto;
            clip-path: ellipse(1000px 100% at top);
           
        }
        .backgroundContainer {
            width: 100vw;
            height: 500px;
            background-color: blue;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
       
        }
        .content {
            background-color:red;
            position:absolute;
            left: 50%;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            text-align:center;
            width: 50vw;
        }
        .btn {
            position:absolute;
            top: 93%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
```

```html
 <div class="container">
        <div class="parent">
            <div class="backgroundContainer"></div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>Lorem</p>
                <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn">Click Me</button>
    </div>
```

hope i explained it well

Comment: Thankyou man. This solution works. You explained it very well. Thankyou again!

Answer (score 0):

I did it without the clip-path so if you must use clip-path you can change some of it .
i used the border-radius and position absolute to make a backGround and then placed the button where i wanted it

```css
 body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .parent {
            width: 100%;
            height: 420px;
            overflow: hidden;
            position:relative;
            background-color:yellow;
           
        }
        .backgroundContainer {
            width: 120vw;
            height: 400px;
            background-color: blue;
            position: absolute;
            left: -10%;
            top: 0;
            border-radius: 0% 0% 50% 50%;
        }
        .content {
            background-color:red;
            position:absolute;
            left: 50%;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            text-align:center;
            width: 50vw;
        }
        .btn {
            position:absolute;
            top: 95%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
        <div class="backgroundContainer">
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <p>Lorem</p>
            <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p>
        </div>
        <button class="btn">Click Me</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: i have no problem achieving this through the border radius infact i have already tried this but the problem is that the curve i want to have on my border cannot be done through border radius so thats why i am using clip-path.

Comment: so use clip-path on the parent. the button position is absolute to the parent, so just change its distance from top it should not make any problem. @saadkhan